# android checking whether connection is lost [ context free ]

Tags: android, network-programming

I want to know if there is a way to listen change in network, to be specific is it possible to generate an event when there is no INTERNET( when changing from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1 ) wherever inside the activities regardless of context ?

Comment: What do you mean by "regardless of context"? That you cannot use any instance of Context?

Comment: I meant like initializing once being able to work everywhere (something like static listener logic)

Comment: you can use application context right? which can be referenced static